# Error compiling DCMTK from source in MinGW-w64 GCC-8.1.0 "Error: 'FlsAlloc' was not declared in this scope"

Tags: mingw-w64, dcmtk

I am trying to compile [DCMTK](https://github.com/DCMTK/dcmtk/blob/master/INSTALL) from the source through [MinGW32-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/) and Cmake.

I am getting these errors after `mingw32-make` command:

```
In file included from C:/dcmtk/oflog/include/dcmtk/oflog/internal/internal.h:59,
                 from C:\Users\Rodrigo\Downloads\tmp_dcmtk\dcmtk\oflog\libsrc\oflog.cc:35:
C:/dcmtk/oflog/include/dcmtk/oflog/thread/impl/tls.h: In function 'dcmtk::log4cplus::thread::impl::tls_key_type dcmtk::log4cplus::thread::impl::tls_init(PFLS_CALLBACK_FUNCTION)':
C:/dcmtk/oflog/include/dcmtk/oflog/thread/impl/tls.h:127:12: error: 'FlsAlloc' was not declared in this scope
     return FlsAlloc(cleanupfunc);
            ^~~~~~~~
C:/dcmtk/oflog/include/dcmtk/oflog/thread/impl/tls.h:127:12: note: suggested alternative: 'TlsAlloc'
     return FlsAlloc(cleanupfunc);
            ^~~~~~~~
            TlsAlloc
C:/dcmtk/oflog/include/dcmtk/oflog/thread/impl/tls.h: In function 'void* dcmtk::log4cplus::thread::impl::tls_get_value(dcmtk::log4cplus::thread::impl::tls_key_type)':
C:/dcmtk/oflog/include/dcmtk/oflog/thread/impl/tls.h:137:12: error: 'FlsGetValue' was not declared in this scope
     return FlsGetValue(k);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
C:/dcmtk/oflog/include/dcmtk/oflog/thread/impl/tls.h:137:12: note: suggested alternative: 'TlsGetValue'
     return FlsGetValue(k);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
            TlsGetValue
C:/dcmtk/oflog/include/dcmtk/oflog/thread/impl/tls.h: In function 'void dcmtk::log4cplus::thread::impl::tls_set_value(dcmtk::log4cplus::thread::impl::tls_key_type, dcmtk::log4cplus::thread::impl::tls_value_type)':
C:/dcmtk/oflog/include/dcmtk/oflog/thread/impl/tls.h:148:5: error: 'FlsSetValue' was not declared in this scope
     FlsSetValue(k, value);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
C:/dcmtk/oflog/include/dcmtk/oflog/thread/impl/tls.h:148:5: note: suggested alternative: 'TlsSetValue'
     FlsSetValue(k, value);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
     TlsSetValue
C:/dcmtk/oflog/include/dcmtk/oflog/thread/impl/tls.h: In function 'void dcmtk::log4cplus::thread::impl::tls_cleanup(dcmtk::log4cplus::thread::impl::tls_key_type)':
C:/dcmtk/oflog/include/dcmtk/oflog/thread/impl/tls.h:159:5: error: 'FlsFree' was not declared in this scope
     FlsFree(k);
     ^~~~~~~
C:/dcmtk/oflog/include/dcmtk/oflog/thread/impl/tls.h:159:5: note: suggested alternative: 'TlsFree'
     FlsFree(k);
     ^~~~~~~
     TlsFree
mingw32-make[2]: *** [oflog\libsrc\CMakeFiles\oflog.dir\build.make:80: oflog/libsrc/CMakeFiles/oflog.dir/oflog.cc.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:2533: oflog/libsrc/CMakeFiles/oflog.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:157: all] Error 2
```

I found this [link](https://forum.dcmtk.org/viewtopic.php?t=4927) with a similar error, however, no solutions were provided.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

System:

- Windows 10 x64
- MinGW-W64 GCC-8.1.0
- Gcc (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0

Comment: Can you look at your CMake cache and see what is the value of `_WIN32_WINNT`? It should be `0x0600` which should be enough to make the `Fls*` functions declared.

Comment: There is no _WIN32_WINNT in the CMakeCache

Comment: Try adding that preprocessor symbol to the compilation.

Comment: I did not find any variable with this name in the CMake GUI. Neither in the normal configurations nor in the advanced ones. Can you explain how can I add this?

Comment: Add a line like `add_compile_definitions (_WIN32_WINNT=0x600)` to `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: It compiled fine.  However, I got an error when building my project. I will open another question for it. Please, formulate an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MinGW headers do not make all of the Win32 API functions visible by default. Add a line like `add_compile_definitions (_WIN32_WINNT=0x600)` to `CMakeLists.txt` file to make the Vista and later API visible. That should fix your compilation.